# get all tags from category

Tags: categories, tags

i'm displaying all posts by category in my template and i was wondering:
is it possible to get a list of all tags used by that category?

i only found out how to make a tag-dropdown but it's from all articles,
i couldn't find out yet how to filter it by category - any ideas?

here's the link
http://wphacks.com/how-to-display-wordpress-tags-dropdown-menu/

thx in advance

Comment: This shows you how to get tags for a category: http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-trick-function-to-get-tags-related-to-category

Comment: I had same issue with custom taxonomies. Here is a function to use: <https://gist.github.com/sergeliatko/da8f99a1883f3a9c02fef827160f7aee>

Answer (score 6):

*Late answer*

There's [`get_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/) here for that. No need for any custom queries.

Comment: Just adding, yes. This is the way to use this.

Comment: Right answer but, you know...you should put an example for users passing by searching for the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is late but thinks it will help someone.
This is the code that gives you tags list for specific category

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP question

Answer (score 0):

10 year later but still better than never...

Categories and tags are not tied to each other. They are both related to post / product. Therefore, you need to query for the all posts/product and grab their IDs, so you can then query for tags where product/post ID is with in this set of IDs.

See the query below for WordPress Posts:

```
SET @CategoryByID = 1; -- set correct category ID
-- SET @CategoryByName = 'Politics'; -- set correct category name

SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type="post" -- <<< for wordpress post type
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND tt.taxonomy = "post_tag" -- <<< for wordpress post tags
AND p.ID IN
    (SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    WHERE p.post_type="post" <<< for wordpress post type
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND tt.taxonomy = "category" -- <<< for wordpress post category
    AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = @CategoryByID -- <<< search category by id (use one)
    -- AND t.name = @CategoryByName  -- <<< search category by name (use one)
    ORDER BY p.ID)
ORDER BY p.ID
```

See the example query below for WooCommerce Products:

```
SET @CategoryByID = 18; -- set correct category ID
-- SET @CategoryByName = 'T-SHIRT'; -- set correct category name

SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE p.post_type="product" -- <<< for woocommerce post type
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND tt.taxonomy = "product_tag" -- <<< for woocommerce tags
AND p.ID IN
    (SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    WHERE p.post_type="product"
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND tt.taxonomy = "product_cat" -- <<< for woocommerce products
    AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = @CategoryByID -- <<< search category by id (use one)
    -- AND t.name = @CategoryByName  -- <<< search category by name (use one)
    ORDER BY p.ID)
ORDER BY p.ID
```